# Trace in NUnit works only while debugging from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nunit, trace, nunit-2.5

I want to display trace info into Text Output tab in NUnit GUI (ver. 2.5.7, target runtime 4.0):

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
Trace.WriteLine("Hello NUnit");
```

This works fine when I launch NUnit GUI from Visual Studio (2010) via Debug -> Start external application.

But when from .nunit project file and console runner - don't. Why??

Comment: This might be a daft question, but since you didn't mention whether this was set or not, did you check the NUnit settings in Tools, Settings? You need to ensure that the Text Output tab is enabled and that Trace output is checked in the content section.

Comment: @Paddyslacker: Thanks, you're right but fortunately I already checked that settings. http://yfrog.com/n4nunittracep Right? What else can I check? Debug works, plain - don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found not a solution but the reason.

I have `MyProject.Test.dll` (contains tests itself) and `MyProject.dll` (the target of tests).

When I use `Trace.WriteLine()` in `MyProject.dll` expecting appearance in NUnit it disappoints me and fails.

But when I use `Trace.WriteLine()` exactly in `MyProject.Test.dll` - it works. But this makes less sense because I need to trace the target itself to determine the reason of test fail without rewriting.

So will be happy to get know a solution to use trace in target and display it via test.